# php - Can I integrate functions with same content, different names?

Tags: php, function, names

I have a couple of functions inside a class that essentially do the same thing:

```
public function fn_a(){
        return __FUNCTION__;
}
public function fn_b(){
        return __FUNCTION__;
}
public function fn_c(){
        return __FUNCTION__;
}
```

I need those functions to remain in their current names so I intentionally did **not** do:

```
public function fn_($letter){
        return __FUNCTION__.$letter;
}
```

I was hoping for some sort of way to minify the verboseness of code here, since they all do the same. The ultimate situation would be something like this:

```
public functions fn_a, fn_b, fn_c() {
      return __FUNCTION__;
}
```

Another solution, if applicable, might be doing something like Class's "extends":
`fn_b, fn_c extend fn_a`?

What do you think guys?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the purpose of these methods, because tbh, this doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any syntax like the one you suggested is not possible : if you want several distinct functions, you have to declare all those functions.

Still, a possibility could be that your fn_a, fn_b and fn_c functions just be simple wrappers arround a more complex one :

```
public function fn_a(){
    return fn_all('a');
}
public function fn_b(){
    return fn_all('b');
}
public function fn_c(){
    return fn_all('c');
}

public function fn_all($name) {
    // a lot of complex stuff here
}
```

With that, depending on the length on the `fn_all` function, of course, you would reduce the amount of code-duplication.

---

Another idea *(not sure how this could be done with methods, so I'll demonstrate with functions)* would be to use Closures -- which means PHP >= 5.3

The basic idea being that you'd have a first function, that would return another one -- which would bind the parameter passed to the first one :

First, the function that creates the others :

```
function creator($name) {
    return function () use ($name) {
        return $name;
    };
}
```

And, then, let's get three functions, using that creator one :

```
$fn_a = creator('a');
$fn_b = creator('b');
$fn_c = creator('c');
```

And now, calling those three functions :

```
echo $fn_a() . '<br />';
echo $fn_b() . '<br />';
echo $fn_c() . '<br />';
```

We get the following output :

```
a
b
c
```

I've never good at explaining how anonymous functions and closures work -- but searching for "closure" on google should help you understand ; note that you can read tutorial about closures in Javascript : the idea is exactly the same.

*(And, as closures are new in PHP -- arrived with PHP 5.3 -- you will not find as many tutorials as for Javascript)*

Comment: Yeah I anticipated that would be a hurdle. Thanks for the help, I'm gonna stick to the duplication anyway =].

Comment: @Gal : i've edited my answer to add some stuff about closures -- not sure it'll help in your case, but it's useful stuff to know :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This sure helps out a lot. I'm using php 5 so I suppose that would be a good solution. I'm gonna try it out and see how well it goes.

Comment: You're welcome :-) -- (I insist on the 5 **.3** : closures don't exist with PHP <= 5.2) -- Have fun ! Anonymous functions and closures are one of the real nice things that were new in PHP 5.3 ;-)

Comment: Youcould also do this with eval.  The downside with eval is that lots of people tell you not to use it.

Comment: @intuited : with reasons that are not bad, generally ;-) *(like performance impact of `eval`, especially versus opcode cache)*

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: That was mostly tongue-in-cheek, though I do feel that there's too much of a tendency to blindly write off eval as always being a bad idea.  Good point though about performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function fn_catcher($letter) {
        return __FUNCTION__.$letter;
}

public function __call($name) {
        if (substr($name, 0, 3) == 'fn_')
        {
              return $this->fn_catcher($name);
        }
}
```

Like that?